# Get error code of android application run via adb

Tags: android, adb, ios-simulator

I'm setting up my Jenkins CI to run some applications on various platforms.  For Windows, I can do `start /b /wait "" <programPath>` to get the return code of the application.

On Android, I run the application which I've written as follows.  Essentially, run the app, wait until the process is complete, assume success if the application quit without the timeout being reached.

```
%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools\adb -s <deviceId> shell am start -n <appName>/<activityName>
BelowBatchFile.bat" <deviceId> <packageName> <timeoutInSeconds>
```

```
@echo off
REM Args are as follows.  Arg 1 is the device identifier.  Arg 2 is the package name.  Arg 3 is the timeout value in seconds.

for /l %%a in (1, 1, %3) do (
    ping -n 2 127.0.0.1 >NUL 
    %ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools\adb -s %1 shell pidof %2 2>&1 |findstr . || goto :success
)

echo Error, timed out waiting for demo to complete.
exit /b 1

:success
exit /b 0
```

Is there a way I can get the error code from the Android application?  The application is quit using [Application.Quit](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application.Quit.html).  I'm wondering the same for an app run on an iOS simulator.  My Android fallback plan is to use logcat to grab the logs and look for specific log lines to determine success.  This would be slower though.

Comment: Android apps have a different life cycle. The process usually don't exit, instead they stay resident until a different app requires more RAM than available. Therefore waiting for an exit code doesn't really make sense. If you have  batch file you should directly execute it via adb. If you are missing command-line aps you can try to install Termux and it's package manager from F-Droid store (Termux in Google Play is outdated and should not be used).

Comment: In this case I've written the application to quit on completion, and have verified that the above batch script works as intended.

Comment: If it is your program that the advice is simple: don't build an app, instead build a command-line application. Then you can get an exit code. Android contains a lot of Java programs (e.g. `bu`) that are hidden behind a startup script but they are just runnable Jars.

Comment: I'll check if that's possible from Unity. Thanks!